# Invalid syntax when math and lists/ranges are involved

Tags: python

```
sum_of_squares = sum(i ** 2) for i in range(1, 101)
```

I am attempting to square all numbers in a range and sum them up, but for whatever reason, when I run it, it gives me a syntax error pointing at `for`.

I've seen examples almost completely identical to this, several times online, but I cannot figure out what the issue is.

I am having major difficulties with math involving lists/ranges (another example being unable to see if an integer is divisible by all the numbers in a list; it only divides by the first number in the list, constant int and operand errors). any sources online that may be helpful?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is in [good form](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), with an attempt to solve the problem yourself and a decent explanation. Keep at it!

Comment: a search for ["python generator expression syntax"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=python+generator+expression+syntax) would give you the relevant resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to use a generator, but your syntax is wrong:

```
sum(i ** 2 for i in range(1, 101))
```

The generator is the argument to `sum`. The above evaluates to `338350`.